# tcolorbox problems with asymmetric page layout

Tags: margins, tcolorbox, geometry, width, calculations

Using tcolorbox for chapter headings I never had a problem, except when I changed to asymmetric layout. Usually `tcolorbox`'s option `spread sidewards` works just fine in a chapter's heading (you can remove the asymmetric option from the code below and test).

But using asymmetric layout I seem to have to experiment to find some values that could be used to spread to the width. What is causing this behavior and why do I have to manually find some values?

`tcolorbox` default calculation:

[image: chapter head]

manual calculation:

[image: chapter]

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,%
    textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip,asymmetric,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=textwithmarginpar:0mm:0mm,footwidth=textwithmarginpar:0mm:0mm,headsepline,automark}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,colframe=blue,colback=blue,sharp corners=all,
        height=.275\paperheight,valign=bottom,coltext=white,move upwards*,
        if odd page={spread outwards,spread inwards}{spread outwards=-52mm,spread inwards=\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}]
        #2\raggedchapter#3%
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters with even some very long titles to see the text width}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters with even some very long titles to see the text width}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the asymmetric option you have a oneside layout. So you should set toggle enlargement to none:

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,%
    textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip,showframe,asymmetric]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=textwithmarginpar:0mm:0mm,
             footwidth=textwithmarginpar:0mm:0mm,headsepline,automark}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,colframe=blue,colback=blue,sharp corners=all,
        height=.275\paperheight,valign=bottom,coltext=white,move upwards*,
        spread outwards,spread inwards,toggle enlargement=none
        ]
        #2\raggedchapter#3%
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters with even some very long titles to see the text width}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters with even some very long titles to see the text width}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters}
    \chapter{Let's do some chapters}
\end{document}
```

[image]